# Basic Routing Issue with Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, routes

Noobie here using Node/Express. I've built an app using jQuery Date Range slider, allowing users to select a date range and pull data from a Socrata SODA API. Working version hosted [here.](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/seattleservices/public/index.html?X-Amz-Date=20160628T155230Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Signature=d8d70e229d575420614b44818675b4b051517f87ef9b03f7f9e8ce4aa580a6bd&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAIIU64TFVGOEMSSZQ/20160628/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=Host&x-amz-security-token=FQoDYXdzENj//////////wEaDFbNXrqOQE/P0IY08SLHAdCF897NdOhsCkq%2BWe%2Bz8pFzdblP2gGRk6PfhmujRoBIJEOXTmB/Cb0RZD3glH4yGJ7fb3miILjGMJA80P3lXo2P%2BN9lB6N/YLucu4EnBXKCE%2BmMIiCsM%2BW7EhpC00Hehu%2B464Un9tNwDyJWX0UeNXgN6lHZadkiqsNkCs0tKF1vzjLK05c/8AIGyBYPNKdFU8TpCrYJCtgH%2B0rzC5Ra/7LOKcQU5Y9S9v%2Bq%2Bn0okxe/vlfKlTQPea6G6Y6V0bkDjAzBNt5FcTQozqPKuwU%3D)

My goal is for user to be able to refresh the page after a query (or Copy/paste/share the URL after a query) and be able to load the same results. I've managed to modify the URL correctly with this:

```
function changeURL(startDate, endDate) { 
  window.history.pushState("ChangeDates", "Title", "/fire/dates?start="+startDate+"%end="+endDate+"");
}
```

So after running a query the URL is something like:

`[root]/fire/dates?start=2015-01-01%end=2015-02-11`

The challenge I'm having is in routing. Currently a refresh will hit a 404. How to I set up Express to route any url requests with the `/fire/[param]` to the home page, then pass on the params to trigger the query again?

Thanks very much all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you keep the params on the client side using a hash like:

```
yourremotadress.org/#start=xxx&end=yyy
```

You could access the hash variables via:

```
window.location.hash
```

So simply read and parse the hash on page load, start the query and show the data?

Comment: This looks great, thanks. Think I got mixed up between parameters and hashes. Will give it a try.